# How do I use a hashed url in sass with webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader, webpack-file-loader

I've configured [webpack caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) using `contenthash`:

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[contenthash:7].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images',
              publicPath: '/public/images',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

How do I reference these hashed URLs in my scss files?

Answer (score 0):

`css-loader` handles this. Start `url` with `~` if using a resolve alias